# Increase the width of a row inside a box-title

Tags: html, adminlte

I'm trying to create two columns in a box-title within the box-header. It works in the box-body but it only spans half of the length of the title. It would be very useful if I could do it. Can anyone help please?

[image]

```
    <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <div class="box-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>New Character</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Old Character</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h6>left side</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h6>right side</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the box-title and I can see the two column across the header. Maybe no the most elegant solution but it works.